# How to output data from module to a page. What are my options?

Tags: theming

I have some code in a module that returns some data. I want to output it in a particular place on the page: Would a block, ctools plugin for panels or a template file be the best option and how would I choose?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already use Panels, and/or if you have an argument to send to your code, i'd advise Panels, definitively...

Great caching powers, multi-instances and rules of access.

But if you don't use it, don't make your site heavier with it and keep it with Blocks.

What about tpl.php ?

Comment: However, how do I create something that I can add into panels? Is the ctools plugin the only way?

Comment: for my part I create a function that prints or echoes what I want and I simply call it in a PhP block (by using "Add custom content" in Panels) and use PhP filter. You can call any function defined in your module and send it args the normal way, like <?php myfunction(%node:nid); ?>. Panels is very handy there, because it gives you all sorts of data to use as arguments. You can do the same with blocks and PhP filters, but without access to data.